# How to import the chrono library which is required in Typescript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, requirejs

I need to import this library [github: chrono](https://github.com/wanasit/chrono) in my Typescript project but the problem is that it doesn't work no matter what I try.

I have tried:

```
import chrono from 'chrono';
import * as chrono from 'chrono';
import {chrono} from 'chrono'
```

But that wasn't the right way. How should I import it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems you should import it from `chrono-node`

```
import * as chrono from 'chrono-node';
```

As mentioned in its [document](https://github.com/wanasit/chrono#usage), it says you need to require the `chrono-node` as follows:

```
var chrono = require('chrono-node');
```

So you need to import it from `chrono-node` too.